# Script will not write the headers to a csv

Tags: python, csv, web-crawler

I am trying to write some simple crawlers to get some data for me from various online stores.
Now, I have written several for sites that have the structure standardized, but this one has given me nothing but grief.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

delay = 3
safety = 30
page = 1
max_pages = 150

#url call


browser_header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}

filename = 'some file.csv'
f = open(filename, 'w')
headers = 'col 1 , col 2 , col 3 , col 4 , col 5 , Link\n'
f.write(headers)
```

It simply will not write the csv headers or anything else in the file (the file gets created, its just empty) and I'm at a loss to why.

edit: The rest of the script works fine, it prints out all the stuff I want, it just doesn't write it to the CSV.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the file to flush the write buffer to disk.  Add

```
f.close()
```

To the end of the script.

Or better still, use a context to open the file so it closes automatically.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(headers)
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed an indent on it and it wasn't throwing any errors. Thanks a bunch.